# Disable CSS for specific control only in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, controls

I have custom CSS for checkbox control into my web form, which is linked on the Master page hence reflect to all child page.

Now, In my gridview I have checkboxes and I don't want to keep the same checkbox sytle. How to disable CSS for checkboxes inside gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way to change the CSS the checkboxes in your GridView is to:

1. Add a CSS-class to your gridview (example: **gridView**)
2. Add this CSS in your stylesheet file:

**.gridView input[type=checkbox]{**

margin:Xpx Xpx Xpx Xpx;

..
..your style attributes...)

**}**

This will **only** affect the **checkboxes** that **is children** to an element that has CSS-class "**gridView**".

Comment: Hopefully you don't need to support old browsers as these attribute selectors (inevitably) don't work in IE6.

Comment: Youre right.. Here in Sweden we dont care about IE6 anymore... Reason:
http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-SE-monthly-201003-201103